# How to display Richfaces commandButton on hover

Tags: hover, richfaces, visibility, commandbutton

Is there a simple way to show a commandButton when I hover an outer div?

```
<h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="galleryPreview">
      <a4j:commandButton value="Start from here" styleClass="commandButton"
      action="#{skinningBean.setCurrentSkinAndForwardToEditor(skin, false)}" />
</h:panelGroup>
```

So I guess I have to initially hide my buttons like `visibility: hidden;`

Is it possible to set all elements in my div visible on hover?

Something like

```
.galleryPreview:hover {
    border: 1.5px solid #6bba29;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just have to set the class of the commandButton to visible, not the outer div

```
.galleryPreview:hover .commandButton{
    visibility: visible;
}
```